# DbContext / Ninject Dependency GetService Slow SingleOrDefault Under Load Test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject

My apologies in advance for the long post as I have been collecting diagnostics but can't quite seem to put my finger on the problem.

EF6 / Web API 2

> To begin I have noticed a slow running endpoint and under load test it get's worse.

Code:

```
//configuration
kernel.Bind<T>()
.To<T>()
.InTransientScope()

//Caller elsewhere in code base
public http.IDependencyScope BeginScope()
{
   return new NinjectScope(_kernel.BeginBlock());
}


public class NinjectScope : IDependencyScope
{
  public object GetService(Type serviceType)
  {
     Debug.WriteLine("COREIOC_Enter GetService Timein: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
     Stopwatch coreIOC = new Stopwatch();
     coreIOC.Start();

    IRequest request = resolutionRoot.CreateRequest(serviceType, null, new Parameter[0], true, true);
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("COREIOC_Complete CreateRequest Elapsed: {0}", coreIOC.Elapsed));

    var abc = resolutionRoot.Resolve(request);
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("COREIOC_Resolve Elapsed: {0}", coreIOC.Elapsed));

    var xyz = abc.SingleOrDefault();
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("COREIOC_SingleDef Resolve Elapsed: {0}", coreIOC.Elapsed));

    coreIOC.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("COREIOC_Exit  Elapsed: {0}", coreIOC.Elapsed));

    return xyz;
  }
}
```

Debug output: (Notice SingleDef is 4 seconds)

```
COREIOC_Enter GetService Timein: 7:15:56 AM:
COREIOC_Complete CreateRequest Elapsed: 00:00:00.0008914
COREIOC_Resolve Elapsed: 00:00:00.0032197    
COREIOC_SingleDef Resolve Elapsed: 00:00:04.4787988
COREIOC_Exit  Elapsed: 00:00:04.4803695
```

> Interestingly subsequent calls show this "spin up" time gone

```
COREIOC_Enter GetService Timein: 7:27:08 AM:
COREIOC_Complete CreateRequest Elapsed: 00:00:00.0000266
COREIOC_Resolve Elapsed: 00:00:00.0018957
COREIOC_SingleDef Resolve Elapsed: 00:00:00.0307401
COREIOC_Exit  Elapsed: 00:00:00.0354408
```

---

So this would be an open and shut case **EXCEPT** under a load test the endpoint is showing the 4 second delay for **EVERY** call. (For example a test run of 250 simultaneous would show each one taking 4+ seconds.)

Hand Written Load Test Code:

```
public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
{
   WebTestRequest request6 = new WebTestRequest("http://localhost:57874/api/acts/10553697");
   request6.Timeout = 120;
   request6.Method = "GET";
   request6.Headers.Add(new WebTestRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer h0aHdT6..."));
   request6.Headers.Add(new WebTestRequestHeader("Accept","application/..."));
   request6.Headers.Add(new WebTestRequestHeader("ContentType", "application/json"));
   request6.ValidateResponse += new EventHandler<ValidationEventArgs>(request6_ValidateResponse);
   yield return request6;
   request6 = null;
}
```

So

1. is my load test incorrect OR,
2. is my EF 6 setup incorrect OR,
3. is my object reuse not correct OR,
4. is there a problem with my actual use of the SingleOrDefault?

I have been through the constructors of the objects being instantiated by ninject and saw nothing in them to be causing a delay.

I did come across this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998117/dbcontext-slow-loading) and as a PluralSight fan I was able to access the course immediately. However it is a seven hour course and in the end I'm not sure it is EF that is causing the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for anyone following. I figured this out but forgot to update here.

So you could say the problem was with Ninject...but you could also make a strong case that is was our design that was the problem.

At the end of the day I'm going to say it was our design that was the problem. A little Ninject flexibility might have kept the design from becoming an issue but if a poor design never surfaces is it still poor design?

Anyway our endpoints were flexible in the operation they would perform. This was fine EXCEPT that coupled with Ninject everything was constructed even if it wasn't needed.

For example an end point might have 13 injected objects but for the given operation only need 3. (The other 10 would be used by other consumers).

Regardless of only needing 3 Ninject would instantiate all 13 and under a 10 minute 750 Constant load...that's alot of JITting going on.

So broke out a couple of end points to more specific purposes and the jit times dropped dramatically.

From our example above:

13 injected objects on one end point become:

1. 3 Injected objects
2. 5 injected objects
3. 4 injected objects
4. 3 Injected objects

So end points 1-4 don't add up to 13 because there is now some redundancy. The same object is injected across some of the end points but at the end of the day everything performs under load as we  would expect.